# Insert method on an enum defined list data structure

Tags: rust

I'm currently learning rust and want to implement my own integer list data structure. The definition of the List is from the rust [tutorial](http://doc.rust-lang.org/tutorial.html#implementing-a-linked-list). This is the exact definition used:

```
enum List {
    Cons(int,Box<List>),
    Nil
}
```

The point where I am struggling is implementing an some kind of insert method, which can be used to insert an element into the list. This is what I tried:

```
impl List {
    fn insert(&mut self,i : int) {
        match *self {
            Nil => {
                let mut l = Cons( i , box Nil );
                self = &mut l;
            }       
            Cons(ref n,box ref xs) => { 
                //TODO
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The problem is that the List assigned to the variable `l` has a different/shorter lifetime than the `self` argument of the insert method. Is there a way to get a new list inside the insert method, which has the same lifetime as self? Maybe using `box` with annotated lifetime `<r'>`? Or is there an other to complete this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment `self = &mut l` does not make any sense. Even if it was allowed by the compiler, it would be just a reassignment of a local variable which hadn't any effect on the method call target.

You need to "reverse" the assignment:

```
*self = l;
```

That is, you need to assign `l` to dereference of `self`, replacing the value behind the pointer. You'd do the same thing in C.

The second case, `Cons`, won't be that easy because Rust won't allow you to move the value out of a reference, and you will need exactly that.

```
Cons(ref n, box ref xs) =>
```

won't work, because `xs` is of type `&List`, and you can't obtain `List` from it without explicit `clone()`. But `clone()`'ing the whole tail of a list upon a mere insert is a big performance hit.

Fortunately, Rust has facilities which allow this kind of operation. They are exposed by `std::mem` module. In this case you will need `replace()` function. With it `insert()` implementation could look like this:

```
use std::mem;

impl List {
    fn insert(&mut self, i: int) {
        let original_head = mem::replace(self, Cons(i, box Nil));
        match *self {
            Cons(_, ref mut tail) => *tail = box original_head,
            _ => unreachable!()
        }
    }
}
```

That is, we replace original value with the new cons cell without tail; that original value is returned by `replace`. Then we update the tail of the new cons cell (which is now located behind `self` reference), putting our original value there. Because we're using enum, we need to do pattern match to extract a reference to the tail of the cons cell, but because we just have put `Cons` into `self`, we can safely disregard `Nil` alternative in the match, putting `unreachable!()` mark there.

This code does perform additional allocation, `box Nil`, which is really unnecessary and will be reverted just when we assign old head to the new tail. It is possible to work around it, but it will require `unsafe` code, as far as I understand it.

Low-level data structures like lists and hash maps can be tricky to implement in Rust because they often need things which are unsafe from Rust perspective, but which are never exposed to the user of the data structure and are in fact safe if the implementation is correct. In these cases you have to drop to the lowest-level Rust features and even `unsafe` code. When you finished writing your structure, however, its users won't need to concern themselves with this unsafety - they will just see and use the safe interface you have provided.